# Something mysterious with PHP, PDO (probably not MySQL) SQLSTATE[42000](1064)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

Something really strange is happening with the following query, when I try it on PhpMyAdmin it works flawlessly, but when I run it from PHP I get the following error.

I'm using PDO...

Maybe I'm blind, or maybe it's the fact that I've been working for so many hours, the thing is that I don't see anything wrong.

> > > **Error message**
> > >
> > > > SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO downsync (id, signature) VALUES ('1','b01c0d494aca29162d815346d0de5f' at line 2

---

> > > ### The query... [Highlighted version (http://pastebin.com/dkYRJCS1)](http://pastebin.com/dkYRJCS1)
> > >
> > > ```
> > > CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS downsync (`id` int(11) NOT NULL, `signature` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL);
> > > INSERT INTO downsync (id, signature) VALUES ('1','b01c0d494aca29162d815346d0de5fd3'),
> > > ('2','bc3d25e2a527a20779914f5c7dc181e5'),
> > > ('3','89bc5c4e013aea0b28e61561ada05770'),
> > > ('4','8ce1daecd2a20c23b1c3344dac07880a'),
> > > ('6','0a679dc54c3654933329fc7bbf01c401'),
> > > ('7','40e6af407141ab652a4cad01f2f30a05'),
> > > ('9','331e12d5136a24483a12a0610f0ecd80'),
> > > ('10','570e68fd6cccd91aaf1173845739d9ab'),
> > > ('11','603e6a77d56a21597563119b319aaf67'),
> > > ('12','7649d3e71223cf543994189fe4053670'),
> > > ('14','825d0a186fd938eb0417a1bf3e30d9c3'),
> > > ('15','4a66d12f56b9ff93332b7c841c986751'),
> > > ('16','7de9d51199cdd316d869510fe97f584c'),
> > > ('17','7ef58d702ea43e02398f3f983c8292f3'),
> > > ('18','430c864532d3352691c76a9517f54498'),
> > > ('19','11a0e5cd2497166b0f85f3e318e6ff2f'),
> > > ('20','9771222ec70e55722e2582f3238f4e44'),
> > > ('21','bffd7ce7a4b59bb439a98ae898e3a703'),
> > > ('22','daf986c8682f856b1828cd4b1c8888b7'),
> > > ('23','3fecc9e7e6291b0ea12bbe60c46d361b'),
> > > ('24','41e49696971f00648f3a3e5971ea765d'),
> > > ('25','0f58aa0ffa8fd6efeb3bb4ccee590d44');
> > > SELECT `downsync.id`,
> > > IF(MD5(CONCAT(
> > > customers.id,
> > > IFNULL(customers.full_name,0),
> > > IFNULL(customers.phone,0),
> > > IFNULL(customers.mobile,0),
> > > IFNULL(customers.email,0),
> > > IFNULL(customers.address,0),
> > > IFNULL(customers.zipcode,0),
> > > IFNULL(customers.city,0),
> > > IFNULL(customers.state,0),
> > > IFNULL(customers.country,0),
> > > IFNULL(customers.gmaps_addrs,0)
> > > )) = signature,1,0) as unchanged
> > > FROM downsync
> > > INNER JOIN customers ON downsync.id = customers.id;
> > > ```

---

> > > ### The Code...
> > >
> > > "Here's the PHP source, I'm a little slow right now, sorry for forgetting it... ;)"
> >
> > ```
> > $query = "
> > CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS downsync (`id` int(11) NOT NULL, `signature`              VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL);
> > INSERT INTO downsync (id, signature) VALUES ('1','b01c0d494aca29162d815346d0de5fd3'),
> > ('2','bc3d25e2a527a20779914f5c7dc181e5'),
> > ('3','89bc5c4e013aea0b28e61561ada05770'),
> > ('4','8ce1daecd2a20c23b1c3344dac07880a'),
> > ('6','0a679dc54c3654933329fc7bbf01c401'),
> > ('7','40e6af407141ab652a4cad01f2f30a05'),
> > ('9','331e12d5136a24483a12a0610f0ecd80'),
> > ('10','570e68fd6cccd91aaf1173845739d9ab'),
> > ('11','603e6a77d56a21597563119b319aaf67'),
> > ('12','7649d3e71223cf543994189fe4053670'),
> > ('14','825d0a186fd938eb0417a1bf3e30d9c3'),
> > ('15','4a66d12f56b9ff93332b7c841c986751'),
> > ('16','7de9d51199cdd316d869510fe97f584c'),
> > ('17','7ef58d702ea43e02398f3f983c8292f3'),
> > ('18','430c864532d3352691c76a9517f54498'),
> > ('19','11a0e5cd2497166b0f85f3e318e6ff2f'),
> > ('20','9771222ec70e55722e2582f3238f4e44'),
> > ('21','bffd7ce7a4b59bb439a98ae898e3a703'),
> > ('22','daf986c8682f856b1828cd4b1c8888b7'),
> > ('23','3fecc9e7e6291b0ea12bbe60c46d361b'),
> > ('24','41e49696971f00648f3a3e5971ea765d'),
> > ('25','0f58aa0ffa8fd6efeb3bb4ccee590d44');
> > SELECT `downsync.id`,
> > IF(MD5(CONCAT(
> > customer.id,
> > IFNULL(customer.name,0),
> > IFNULL(customer.email,0),
> > IFNULL(customer.gmaps_addrs,0)
> > )) = signature,1,0) as unchanged
> > FROM downsync
> > INNER JOIN commerces ON downsync.id = commerces.id;
> > ";
> > ```

```
echo '<pre>';var_dump($query);echo '</pre>';

try {
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);



$stmt = $pdo->query($query);

//> I tried to commet this  and use the query method but it didn't work
//$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
//$stmt->execute($params);

    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
catch(Exception $e) {

    echo 'Exeption:<pre>';var_dump($e->getMessage());echo '</pre><hr>';
    echo 'Error Obj.: <pre>';var_dump($e);echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: These are *two* queries. My guess is you're trying to execute them both in one call in PHP.

Comment: I think we might need your PHP code if this is working from phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @OP: You doubt it is PHP error. But you posted only MySQL code.

Comment: @OP: And, I think, you must be executing all three sql statements at one go from PHP. You have to use [*`multi_query`*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) to execute all together.

Comment: SELECT 'downsync.id' ...
I think here is the issue - Please change to 
    SELECT 'downsync'.'id' ...

Comment: @Prava-MindfireSolutions tried it, didn't do anything. It's probably on the 1st or 2nd statement.

Comment: @Ravinder What's the equivalent to multi-query in PDO? I looked for it and didn't find a thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > > ### Solution:

Separating the 3 queries did the trick

```
$query1 = 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS....';
$query2 = 'INSERT INTO downsync...';
$query3 = 'SELECT downsync.id...';

...

$stmt = $pdo->query($query);
$stmt = $pdo->query($query2);
$stmt = $pdo->query($query3);
```

Thanks @lafor, @Prava - Mindfire Solutions, @Ravinder